# Sequelize 'Inverse' Relationship

Tags: node.js, database, orm, sequelize.js

Not sure if I'm just being silly, but encountered something that's stumped me with regards to Sequelize.

**Preamble**

Let's say you have **Users** and **Projects** like the examples the Sequelize site provides, to keep things simple.

With a *n:m* relationship for this example, one User can be assigned to multiple Projects, and visa versa.

With relationships correctly set up, you should be able to call the following:

```
//To get the projects a user is assigned to:
user.getProjects();

//To get the users assigned to a project:
project.getUsers();
```

**The Issue**

While this is pretty handy already, how to I access the 'inverse' relationship, for instance **Users NOT assigned to a Project**, or **Projects a User IS NOT a part of**?

Would this be achieved via a scope, or can it be achieved with the creation of another relationship?

Kind regards :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is couple of ways that can achieve what you are asking for. First one is to use `getProjects()` or `getUsers()` method to return objects assigned to `User/Project` and use it in order to return the unassigned records (something like `id NOT IN (...)`)

```
user.getProjects().then(projects => {
    let mappedProjects = projects.map(project => {
        return project.id;
    });

    Project.all({
        where: { id: { $notIn: mappedProjects } }
    }).then(projects => {
        // projects not assigned to 'user'
    });
});
```

On the other hand, you can create some instance method like `getUnassignedProjects()` on `User` model that would perform the action above or similar with use of [`sequelize.literal()`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#literalval-sequelizeliteral), [`sequelize.where()`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#whereattr-comparator-logic-sequelizewhere) and [`sequelize.col()`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#colcol-sequelizecol) methods

```
instanceMethods: {
    getUnassignedProjects: function(){
        return sequelize.models.Project.all({
            where: sequelize.where(
                sequelize.col('Project.id'),
                ' NOT IN ',
                sequelize.literal(`(SELECT "projectId" FROM users_projects WHERE "userId" = ${this.id})`)
            )
        });
    }
}
```

Code above would generate query similar to this one

```sql
SELECT "id", "name" FROM "projects" AS "Project" WHERE "Project"."id" NOT IN (SELECT "project" FROM users_projects WHERE "userId" = 1);
```

The `users_projects` is of course the table connecting users and projects in n:m relation.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. Much appreciated. I implemented the instance method as it keeps all the other code neat. Cheers!